# Blazor Webassembly - request from browser to server API return 302 HTTP Code (redirect) - how to process

Tags: ajax, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

Blazor Webassembly App send Ajax HTTP Request to server

```
// blazor page code
async Task GetDataFromServerApi() {

    using (var resp = await Http.GetAsync("Api/ResourceGroup").ConfigureAwait(false)) {
        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) {

            // never come here

        }
    }

}
```

Server API return 302 HTTP Code. Browser immediately process request. Blazor app do not get response and cannot check status code.

[image]

How to catch HTTP 302 response status in Blazor App?

Comment: It's probably because you are not authentified on the API

Comment: @aguafrommars yes, I am not authentified. The question is how to catch 302 response status in Blazor Webassebly

Comment: You cannot, it's managed by the underlying Blazor WASM HttpClient stack which use the browser fetch api. The only possible way is to write your own HttpClient using JSInteropt.

Comment: A second approach is to configure your API for anonymous requests.

Comment: Or catch the exception